# copy all rows with matching field value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to copy all mysql rows with a matching field value into a new row and change one field.

So I have a mysql table with the following fields

```
`lessonplan`, `group`, `category`, `sort_id`, `item`
```

So I want to copy all rows that have `lessonplan=10` and set  change the value of `lessonplan` to `11` for all new rows. Lesson plan is not an auto increment field.

What is best practice for a scenario like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tableName( lessonplan, `group`, category, sort_id, item )
SELECT 11, `group`, category, sort_id, item
FROM   tableName
WHERE  lessonplan = 10
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thought it wouldn't be to hard and Thank you so much!